# Playing PCM stream from Web Audio API on Node.js

Tags: node.js, audio, stream, pcm, web-audio-api

I'm streaming recorded PCM audio from a browser with web audio api.

I'm streaming it with [binaryJS (websocket connection)](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs) to a nodejs server and I'm trying to play that stream on the server using the speaker npm module.

This is my client.  [The audio buffers are at first non-interleaved IEEE 32-bit linear PCM with a nominal range between -1 and +1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer).  I take one of the two PCM channels to start off and stream it below.

```
var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
var Stream = client.send();

recorder.onaudioprocess = function(AudioBuffer){
    var leftChannel = AudioBuffer.inputBuffer.getChannelData (0);
    Stream.write(leftChannel);
}
```

Now I receive the data as a buffer and try writing it to a speaker object from the npm package.

```
var Speaker = require('speaker');

var speaker = new Speaker({
  channels: 1,          // 1 channel
  bitDepth: 32,         // 32-bit samples
  sampleRate: 48000,     // 48,000 Hz sample rate
  signed:true
});

server.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
        stream.on('data', function(data){
            speaker.write(leftchannel);
        });
    });
});
```

The result is a high pitch screech on my laptop's speakers, which is clearly not what's being recorded. It's not feedback either.  I can confirm that the recording buffers on the client are valid since I tried writing them to a WAV file and it played back fine.

The [docs for speaker](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker) and the [docs for the AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) in question

I've been stumped on this for days.  Can someone figure out what is wrong or perhaps offer a different approach?

## **Update with solution**

First off, I was using the websocket API incorrectly.  I updated above to use it correctly.

I needed to convert the audio buffers to an array buffer of integers.  I choose to use [Int16Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Int16Array).  Since the given audio buffer has a range in-between 1 and -1, it was as simple as multiplying by the range of the new ArrayBuffer (32767 to -32768).

```
recorder.onaudioprocess = function(AudioBuffer){

    var left = AudioBuffer.inputBuffer.getChannelData (0);

    var l = left.length;
    var buf = new Int16Array(l)

    while (l--) {
        buf[l] = left[l]*0xFFFF;    //convert to 16 bit
    }

    Stream.write(buf.buffer);

}
```

Comment: To either eliminate or identify the Speaker as the source of error, if you write the buffer on the receiving end to a wav in the same way that you did on the client, does it play back correctly (problem with the Speaker) or as a screeching sound (problem with the stream)? Alternatively, are you able to play a working AudioBuffer through the Speaker?

Comment: Hi, can I find your code somewhere on github?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're sending your stream through as the `meta` object.

According to the docs, [`BinaryClient.send`](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md#clientsenddata-meta) takes a `data` object (the stream) and a `meta` object, in that order. The callback for the [`stream`](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md#event-stream) event receives the stream (as a `BinaryStream` object, not a `Buffer`) in the first parameter and the `meta` object in the second.

You're passing `send()` the string `'channel'` as the stream and the `Float32Array` from `getChannelData()` as the meta object. Perhaps if you were to swap those two parameters (or just use `client.send(leftChannel)`) and then change the server code to pass `stream` to `speaker.write` instead of `leftchannel` (which should probably be renamed to `meta`, or dropped if you don't need it), it might work.

Note that since `Float32Array` isn't a stream or buffer object, BinaryJS might [try to send it in one chunk](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md#clientsenddata-meta). You may want to send `leftChannel.buffer` ([the `ArrayBuffer` behind that object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array)) instead.

Let me know if this works for you; I'm not able to test your exact setup right now.

Comment: I indeed faulted with the websocket API.  I updated my answer with the correct usage.  This was part of the error and I figured out the other part which had to do with the audio buffer.  Since you helped figure out part of the problem I'll award you the bounty.