# Web Audio- streaming file from server to client

Tags: javascript, audio, types, web-audio-api

I'm trying to stream audio from a server containing an audio file to a client using BinaryJS. My code was inspired by the code in this question: [Playing PCM stream from Web Audio API on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876152/playing-pcm-stream-from-web-audio-api-on-node-js)

Here's what my server code looks like:

```
// create a BinaryServer using BinaryJS
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
// gotta be able to access the filesystem
var fs = require('fs');

// create our server listening on a specific port
var server = BinaryServer({port: 8080});

// do this when a client makes a request
server.on('connection', function(client){
    // get the audio file
    var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/JDillaLife.mp3');

    // convert to int16
    var len = file.length;
    var buf = new Int16Array(len);

    while(len--){
        buf[len] = data[len]*0xFFFF;
    }

    var Stream = client.send();
    Stream.write(buf.buffer);

    console.log("Server contacted and file sent");
});
console.log('Server running on port 8080');
```

And my client code:

```
var Speaker = require('speaker');
var speaker = new Speaker({
    channels: 2,
    bitDepth: 32,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    signed: true
});

var BinaryClient = require('binaryjs').BinaryClient;
var client = BinaryClient('http://localhost:8080');
client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
    stream.on('data', function(data){
        speaker.write(data);
    });
});
```

This is a very rough draft and I'm almost certain it won't play nicely right away, but right now it's throwing an error when I run that seems to take issue with the line `var buf = new Int16Array(len);`, and I'm not sure why this is happening. It says there's a "type error," but I'm not sure why this would happen when assigning a new object to an empty variable. I'm new to JS (and the whole untyped languages thing in general) so is this an issue with what I'm assigning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're accessing file.length, while file is a Stream object which I don't think have a length property. So what you're doing is basically saying

```
 new Int16Array(undefined);
```

and hence the type error.

fs.createReadStream is documented here; https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

You can use the Stream object to read data in chunks using stream.read(256), as documented here; https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size

Hopefully that gives you enough pointers to proceed!